# How to clear blank entries from Titanium Backup (pro)?

Tags: titanium-backup

I often delete those backups which are no longer useful to me. Backup entries are removed from list (popup), but app/element entries aren't removed even when those app/element are not installed.

**Here's an example:**

[image: Titanium Backup List]

You can see `No backup yet` & the app is no longer installed. How to remove these entries?

I'm rooted and have latest version of Titanium Backup Pro.

Comment: How are you deleting the backups? If I delete a backup from Titanium's UI and then refresh the list the deleted backup is no longer listed.

Comment: @eldarerathis Deleted backup entries are removed from list, but not the main app entry (with ZERO backups).

Comment: I've clarified with screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot suggests you simply uninstalled those apps. In TB, hit the menu button, select "batch processing", scroll to the end of the list. There you'll find "Delete Backups". Second item in that section should read "Delete backups of uninstalled apps" (or the like -- I run a localized version, was just back-translating). That should get you rid of those "striked" entries.

For more details (as well as solution to other TB-related issues), you might want to visit the [Titanium Backup Knowledge Base](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb), which provides you with a user's guide, FAQ, troubleshooting tips, How-Tos, and more.

As for the one circled entry, the linked knowledge-base a.o. states:

> You can easily remove orphan data by running the “Remove orphan data” batch job.

Comment: It just removes the backup of uninstalled apps, not its entries! See the highlighted item in screenshot. It has no backup, so batch operation can't work on it.

Comment: Ah -- I was only looking at the last entries, sorry. From your "-1" I take it *you* missed the link in my answer. So let me quote what is found behind it: **You can easily remove orphan data by running the “Remove orphan data” batch job.** I will update my answer and explicitly quote it there :)

Comment: Why did you expect me to visit link to general knowledge base which may be a big encyclopedia? :) Well, "Remove Orphan Data" batch operation is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that -- "may be" is an understatement, I admit :) Glad I could help. And "may be" I try to be a bit more precise next time from the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

The app is uninstalled but still in the system partion root/custom/app or root/vendor/operater/app after finding these apk's you need to delete them